# State tax implications of a dual citizen who moved overseas to other country of citizenship

Tags: united-states, international, state-income-tax, citizenship

Last state of residence was NY, but I have no property / other ties to the state. I do however maintain bank/investment accounts using a relatives address just to make things easier regarding mail/etc.

I have no intention of returning to NY/US. Can the address thing trip me up? Is it worth closing all of my accounts and re-opening using the international address?

Edit: According https://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/file/pit_definitions.htm, I shouldn't be considered a resident for tax purposes. My confusion lies in where the "source of income" is for my investments if my brokerage accounts are open under my previous NY address, but I now reside overseas.

Comment: You need a certified fiduciary, and/or to do your own due diligence.  https://www.tax.ny.gov/  This is squarely in the area of, "Do I need to pay taxes to XYZ?"  Somewhere in that website it tells you who needs to pay taxes.  Also, have you checked with your banks to see if you can change the addresses on the accounts?

Comment: According to the website I wouldn't be considered a resident for tax purposes. However, I guess my confusion is where the "source of income" is in terms of my investments if my brokerage accounts are open under my NY address, but I'm resident overseas.